# How to bind pure virtual methods form class A to methods of class B in child of both without lots of code?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have several pairs of classes in two separate projects (Qt and another one) and one class in the every pair contains several tens of pure virtual functions while the other class in pair has several tens of methods with exactly the same methods but those methods are not derived because the classes are in different projects. For example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
    void test() {
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    }
};
```

What I need is a class which can act as A and B at the same time:

```
class C: public A, public B {
public:
    void test() override { B::test(); }
};
```

The issue I'd like to solve is that there are hundreds of methods so the code looks like

```
void test1() override { B::test1(); }
void test_another() override { B::test_another(); }
void foobar(int param1, int param2) override { B::foobar(param1, param2);
```

And I'd like to avoid this redundant code. Of course, I can write a macro but this macro must be still called for every of these methods. Is there any way to achieve shorter code? I cannot modify class `B` but have an ability to do modifications in `A`.

**UPDATE**

Here is some actual code:

```
class MyControl {
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class WidgetControl: public MyControl, public QWidget {
public:
    WidgetControl(): MyControl(), QWidget() {}
public:
    void show() override {QWidget::show();} //<- there is not only show(), but almost all other methods
};

class ActionControl: public MyControl, public QAction {
public:
    ActionControl(): MyControl(), QAction() {}
public:
    void show() override {
        // do another actions, since QAction cannot show() and hide(). Instead it's possible to remove or add it to parent QMenu
    }
};

int main() {
    MyControl* control1 = new WidgetControl();
    MyControl* control2 = new ActionControl();
    control1->show();
    control2->show();
}
```

Comment: If B implements the function and C derives from B, then why do you need to override it in C?

Comment: one solution is to add a template parameter to B and inherit from that one. then `C` becomes `class C: public B<A>`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use `B`'s non-virtual implementations to implement a virtual interface provide by `A`?

Comment: @MarkB exactly!

Comment: @AnonMail to be able to do `A* a = new C(); a->test();`

Comment: @Raxvan I cannot modify `B`

Comment: @Grief what is the motivation to do this?

Comment: @AnonMail I've updated the question with an example of real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as a result of the OP's question update I totally threw away my original answer and replaced it with this one.

I don't see a way to avoid spelling out all the functions in an interface but you *can* make all the delegation happen once in a CRTP base class rather than delegating from the child upwards. If your code is suitably templated already you can even remove the pure virtual base interface and work only with the CRTP base.

```
class MyControl
{
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

template <typename Child, typename Impl>
class MyControlInterposer : public MyControl
{
    void show() override { static_cast<Impl*>(static_cast<Child*>(this))->show(); }
};

class QWidget
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "QWidget::show()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class QAction
{
};

class WidgetControl: public MyControlInterposer<WidgetControl, QWidget>, public QWidget
{
public:
    WidgetControl(): MyControlInterposer(), QWidget() {}
};

class ActionControl: public MyControlInterposer<ActionControl, ActionControl>, public QAction
{
public:
    ActionControl(): MyControlInterposer(), QAction() {}
public:
    void show() {
        // do another actions, since QAction cannot show() and hide(). Instead it's possible to remove or add it to parent QMenu
        std::cout << "ActionControl::show()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyControl* control1 = new WidgetControl();
    MyControl* control2 = new ActionControl();
    control1->show();
    control2->show();
}
```

Output:

```
QWidget::show()
ActionControl::show()
```

Comment: Nice! It took some time for me to understand CRTP but it seems that it perfectly fits. Your answer advances the question: I didn't see the wood for the trees, while the approach you suggest doesn't reduce the amount of code mentioned in the question (even increases it a bit), it definitely helps with the more serious problem - classes that are derived from QWidget e.g. QLabel, QMenu etc. I'd prefer to keep template magic in one place, so I'd leave base interface. Now, when I understood how bigger the code duplication could be it looks fine for me - I'll write some macros.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using dynamic polymorphism like this:

```
class MyControl {
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};
```

which requires you to add an extra child off of a lot of other types that already meet the concept you're trying to establish, I would suggest a different approach. Let's try *static* polymorphism. Basically, instead of using a pointer to polymorphic base class to erase the type, we're going to have an object that erases the type - which would let us use this new "base" class with 3rd party libraries that don't conveniently implement our interface using traditional OOP methods.

With [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html), this would look something like:

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_show), show, 0)
using MyControl = any<has_show<void()>>;
```

This let's me add anything into `MyControl` that has some member function named `show` that takes no arguments, like:

```
MyControl c1 = QWidget();
c1.show(); // calls QWidget::show()
```

`c1` here owns the `QWidget`, it has value semantics, although there are ways to do it differently - the library has many many features.

You still have to manually provide a list of signatures into `any<>`, but at least you don't have to introduce a ton of types solely to meet your polymorphic requirements.

Comment: I tried to understand how it works under the hood but for me it looks even darker than Alexandrescu's black magic. It drives CLion (IDE) crazy, `BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER` got underlined with red right away. GCC error messages around are unclear and what is probably most important - the type `any<has_show<void()> >` not only becomes named longer when there are tens of has_members but also is not flexible enough without other boost-templated code. I must admit, it works and it might be useful in some cases, but not in mine, sorry. I'll upvote yours but accept Mark's answer.